# Need help in adding Python code as Kibana plugin

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, kibana

I have a python code which triggers email based on the data inserted into the Elastic Search. My standalone python code is working as expected. I want to put this code as a Kibana plugin. Is it possible to do this functionality? If yes, any pointers? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create plugins for Kibana, but not with Python.

Kibana is a Node.js application and the plugins for it need to be developed using the same framework, if you want to use your code you will need to migrate it from python.

This [document](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#contributing-code) in the official github repository has more information about how to build a kibana plugin.